# Creating desire lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, flow-map, origin-destination

How can I show the flow coming from an Origin-Destination matrix as desire lines?

I need a result like the one in the picture below.

[image: desire lines]

I need to scale them proportionally to its value (coming from a linked MDB) and I like that the lines are a bit curved (but I can use straight lines too).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using the QGIS plugin [Flowmapper](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FlowMapper/).  The attached image is a sample from the plugin documentation.

[image]