# Table analysis with QGIS

Tags: qgis, visualisation

Sometimes I think about possible analysis using GIS models (I use QGIS 1.8), and I always think about few types of visualization techniques: demographics, traffic flows, distance ones.

I discover many possible criteria (and I begin to use it) analysis and I like to collect the most important one in a single item to help the consultation.

Is this a good idea or not?

I try with some examples of a project where I worked on

[image: generated traffic by zone]

generated traffic by zone by magnitude

[image: traffic by zone]

traffic IN/OUT zone by zone by bar diagram

[image: journey time on different routes]

journey time on different routes

[image: OD from a zone]

OD from a zone ([Flow Mapper](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FlowMapper/) plugin from [How to create desire lines in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64045))

[image: quantity and quality parks on links]

quantity and quality parks on links

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to know? It's still not clear.

Comment: It looks like you are wanting feedback on your ideas and that is too broad for the Q&A format of GIS SE.  I recommend reading the [**help**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help) and also [**What makes a good question?**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question) to get some ideas on how to focus your question on a single issue.

Comment: On my first work it happened that the boss ask me info about this land and I start to go on with some analysis. I undestand the possibility of the OD analysis in this forum after the discovery of Flow Mapper plugin. And probably there are a lot of other possible analysis from GIS models, I only would like to undestand how other users use GIS to improve my skill on it, so I am not able to focus the question on a single issue. (Maybe this is not the right way to ask for it)

Comment: I like your pictures but it is still not clear what you are asking. Are you asking for examples of good maps? There is a thread for that: [What Makes a Map Beautiful?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3083/753) You'll probably have to dig a bit to find more analytical rather than just visual answers though.

Comment: My aim is to discover multiple analisys that we can offer to customer. So it is similar to the link you post here but I would prefer somthing like: I make this map to rapresent this for this purpose, indipendent from how beautiful is the final result