# How can I use GIS in concrete factories?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Ideas for a GIS proposal.
I would like to propose the use of GIS in a concrete factory.
Can anyone help with some basic projects, and ways to make GIS viable to the benefit of the company?
I use arcmap.

Comment: This question is going to require some more detail in order for it to be answerable. What problem would you like to solve?

Comment: In fact, I want to make aproject (proposal) and I want some special ideas .

Comment: there are certainly more ways, that was just a 20 second run.

Comment: it seems a duplicate of a question of mine: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74013/our-best-table-analysis-with-gis and I do not find it so bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. geocode job tickets as they come in. (with address)
2. keep database of volumes in stock, in job tickets, and locations,
   distances of resources.
3. calculate distances to jobs, (add to billing/cost estimates).
4. put tracking devices in trucks and track: speeds, routes, stops,
   delays, traffic re-routes.

Comment: Nice answer for a really bad question. I thought it was programming question re: factory pattern.